# Speed differences between proc, Proc.new, lambda, and stabby lambda

Tags: ruby, performance, lambda, proc

Procs and lambdas [differ](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) with respect to method scoping and the effect of the `return` keyword. I am rather interested in the performance differences between them. I wrote a test as shown below:

```
def time(&block)
  start = Time.now
  block.call
  p "that took #{Time.now - start}"
end
def test(proc)
  time{(0..10000000).each{|n| proc.call(n)}}
end
def test_block(&block)
  time{(0..10000000).each{|n| block.call(n)}}
end
def method_test
  time{(1..10000000).each{|n| my_method(n)}}
end

proc1 = Proc.new{|x| x*x}
proc2 = proc{|x| x*x}
lam1 = lambda{|x| x*x}
lam2 = ->x{x*x}

def my_method(x)
  x*x
end

test(proc1)
test(proc2)
test(lam1)
test(lam2)
test_block{|x| x*x}
test(method(:my_method))
method_test
```

The result of this code is shown below.

```
"that took 0.988388739"
"that took 0.963193172"
"that took 0.943111226"
"that took 0.950506263"
"that took 0.960760843"
"that took 1.090146951"
"that took 0.644500627"
```

`method(:my_method)` is the slowest, which is because it checks a look up table for each iteration in the loop.

Similarly, another test as below:

```
def test2(&block)
  time{(0..1000000).each{block.call}}
end

test2{Proc.new{|x| x*x}}
test2{proc{|x| x*x}}
test2{lambda{|x| x*x}}
test2{->(x){x*x}}
```

returns this result:

```
"that took 0.415290453"
"that took 0.378787963"
"that took 0.3888118"
"that took 0.391414639"
```

`Proc.new` is the slowest creation method, which is because we have the overhead of creating an entire object to wrap our proc.

I assert that the execution time of the procs and lambdas are the same as one another regardless of their creation method.

- Why is normal method invocation so much faster than procs and lambdas (1/3 time reduction)?
- Do people think this is likely to change with different block functions etc.?
- Are there any other (performance based) reasons to chose between the different approaches?

Comment: There are *no* performance-based reasons to choose between them. They're different things, build for different purposes. Trying to compare them for performance is like comparing the speed of race cars and tow-trucks.

Comment: Btw, you might want to know about http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html :]

Comment: @meagar I'd dispute that, if I don't put my proc or lambda inside a method and never call return or break from it (very common for me as I try and write many of my scripts in a functional style and using the wonderful new lazy iterators that we have) then they are functionally equivalent, (aren't they?) in that case what should I use to pick between them, I currently use the stabby lambda as it's quickest to type, but I'd like to make an informed decision. In the situation I just proposed, are they different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it seems you have three questions. The middle one is unclear to me, so I will address the other two:

**Why is normal method invocation so much faster?**

This is the easier of the questions.

First realize that the times involved here are for function call *overhead*. I did my own timings based on your code (but with an identity function instead of multiplication), and non-direct invocations took 49% longer. With one multiplication, non-direct invocations took only 43% longer. In other words, one reason why you're seeing a large disparity is that your function itself is doing almost nothing. Even a single multiplication makes 6% of the difference "vanish". In a method of any reasonable complexity, the method call overhead is usually going to be a relatively small percentage of the overall time.

Next, remember that a proc/block/lambda is essentially a chunk of code that is being carried around (though a block literal cannot be saved into a variable). This implies one more level of indirection than a method call...meaning that at the very least the CPU is going to have to traverse a pointer to something.

Also, remember that Ruby supports closures, and I'm betting there is some overhead in deciding which environment the indirect code should run in.

On my machine, running a C program that invokes a function directly has 10% less overhead than one that uses a pointer to a function. An interpreted language like Ruby, where closures are also involved, is definitely going to use more.

My measurements (Ruby 2.2) indicate a direct method invocation takes about as long as 6 multiplications, and an indirect invocation takes about as long as 10.

So while the *overhead* is nearly twice as large, remember that the overhead in both cases is often relatively small.

**Are there any other (performance based) reasons to chose between the different approaches?**

I'd say given the above data the answer is usually no: you're much better off using the construct that gives you the most maintainable code.

There are definitely good reasons to choose one over the other. To be honest, I'm surprised about the difference I see between lambdas and blocks (on my machine, lambdas have 20% less overhead). Lambdas create anonymous methods that include parameter list checking, so if anything I would expect it to be slightly slower, but my measurements put it ahead.

That the direct invocation is faster simply isn't surprising at all.

The place where this kind of thing makes a difference is in very frequently called code where the overhead adds up to be noticeable in wall-clock kinds of ways. In this case, it can make sense to do all manner of ugly optimizations to try to squeeze a bit more speed, all the way up to inlining code (dodge the function-call overhead altogether).

For example, say your application uses a database framework. You profile it and find a frequently-called, small (e.g. less than 20 multiplications worth of work) function that copies the data from the database result into data structures. Such a function might comprise the lion's share of the result processing, and simply inlining that function might shave off significant amounts of CPU time at the expense of some code clarity.

Simply inlining your "square function" into a long numeric calculation with a billion steps could save you dramatic amounts of time because the operation itself takes a lot less time than even a direct method invocation.

In most cases, though, you're better off with clean, clear code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. as it happened you answered all three of my questions. To clarify the second one was asking whether the body of the function would change the relative speeds of the different function call syntaxes and the answer seems to be, no, not the relative speed, just the absolute speed of the invocations (seems to be implied by your points).

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, glad to help.

Comment: so in crux, if the calculations are heavy and is to ve invoke a single time we can inline them. But if its simple its better to call via a method. Am i right ?